# phpMyAdmin not found

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd.conf

My phpMyadmin installed from portmaster works just fine execpt when I omit the trailing slash from the main URL, I got a not found error :

> http://192.168.1.161/phpmyadmin

This link does not work and displays this error :

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /phpmyadmin was not found on this server.

Here is my configuration :

```
Alias /phpmyadmin/ "/usr/local/www/phpMyAdmin/"

<Directory "/usr/local/www/phpMyAdmin/">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options -Indexes
options -FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride all
Require ip 192.168 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

Can you please help me with this ? thank you.

Comment: .. Why don't you just use it with a trailing slash?

Comment: Not every single user is aware of it, other links works just fine with or without the trailing slash which is the normal behaviour.

Comment: Alias /phpmyadmin "/usr/local/www/phpMyAdmin/" ?

Comment: Already tried but no success.

Comment: to yagmoth555 : it is quit odd but I tried Alias modification before you post it but it did not work at the time, hours later it worked, I guess because I did not restart Apache at the moment, but anyway thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it by myself this time, this did the trick :

Replace this :

```
Alias /phpmyadmin/ "/usr/local/www/phpMyAdmin/"
```

With this :

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "/usr/local/www/phpMyAdmin/"
```

I had simply to remove the trailing slash from the Alias.

Thanks for everyone, I hope this will help someone someday.

Comment: That is **exactly** what Yagmoth suggested in a comment above, which you claimed you had tried unsuccessfully.  **Accuracy is important in sysadmin.**

Comment: did you take the time to read my comment in response to Yagmoth ?

Comment: Assuming you mean that dated 2015-07-16 10:02, then no, because you hadn't written it when I made my comment above, and I had no way of knowing you'd written it since.  Having now read it, I'm confirmed in my opinion that this question is off-topic, since I feel that anyone who doesn't know that apache needs to be told to re-read its config file has no business [managing apache systems in a business environment](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Use one of these:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

or

```
DirectorySlash On
```

The first needs mod_rewrite enabled, the second needs mod_dir.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work, it was one of the first tweaks I tried.